# The method setAdapter(SimpleAdapter) is undefined for the type Object

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am still working on [that tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html) and I can't get it to work. The error occurrs in line 38 `lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);`

My whole MainActivity.java can be seen below. If anyone could help fix this error and tell my why it occurrs, I could finally run the app. I have tested the app with line 38 commented but the app just crashed after startup. Thanks for any help. I am still very much a newb.

```
package com.example.lern;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Data to Show
    List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void initList() {
        // Populating them planets

        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Earth"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));

    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Object lv;
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    planet.put(key, name);

    return planet;
}

//This is a simple adapter
//The keys are used to retrieve the data
//the View id is Used to show the data. The <key number and the view id must match
SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]
{"planet"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this error? Check the tutorial again.

Comment: Eclipse is telling me that, so I assume so.

Comment: lv is an object should be listview

Comment: please refer this link http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php or http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/

Comment: @Marius Can you not see that the tutorial's code and your code are different? Where the hell does the tutorial use the line `Object lv`?

Comment: I can see that. I put it there, because I saw that in another forum. I will now try it with the link provided by Narayan Soni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setAdapter() method is the method of a `ListView` and it is undefined for the type `Object`

```
Object lv;
lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
```

Follow the tutorial properly..

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"planet"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
```